# Is any Products images renderer class Script\QuickView\Helpers\Html is possible in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, quickview

> Hi guys, i am trying to create products quick view here i am facing on
>   one issue related to Html class actually which is responsible for
>   products image rendering purpose.
>
> Is any one have any idea please tell me.

Actually i am using this link [enter link description here](https://github.com/hryvinskyi/magento2-quickview)

> Error Code

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Script\Base\Helpers\Html' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Script\QuickView\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml:17 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(59): include() #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor), 'E:/xampp/htdocs...', Array) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor.php(505): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('E:/xampp/htdocs...') #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(300): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery\Interceptor->fetchView('E:/xampp/htdocs...') #4 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() #5 E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\generated\code\Magen in E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\app\code\Script\QuickView\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml on line 17
```

Comment: Rename `Helpers` folder to `Helper` if its still not work add your gallery..phtml code in question

Comment: yes you are right i used gallery.phtml file its working fine but i think this class is not working after changing to helpers to helper